# What microdata should i use for purchase guide segment in category page?

Tags: microdata, google-rich-snippets, rich-snippets

I have many category pages and each category has many products and companies and one guide for users (user guide about category subject).

What microdata should I use for purchase guide for each category page?

If I use article, Problem is logo! I don't want show my logo (Publisher logo) at the end of user guide segment!

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want the Article rich result from Google? Or do you ask for a suitable way to mark it up with Schema.org, no matter if this results in a Rich Snippet or not?

Comment: @unor I asked for a suitable way to mark it up and google can understand it as a guide.Not a plain text in my html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want show the Puplisher logo visible at the end of the article you can use

```
<span itemprop="logo" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
  <meta itemprop="url" content="http://www.domain.com/logo.jpg">
  <meta itemprop="width" content="600">
  <meta itemprop="height" content="60">
</span>
```

So you have a valid microdata article. But it will show in the Serps.